# Does Heroku charge any from creadit card for custom domain?

Tags: heroku, dns

I want to point to custom domain. For account verification, Heroku ask for credit card details.
But I want to ask that for using a custom domain on Heroku does it charged any money from credit card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> .. for using a custom domain on Heroku does it charged any money from credit card

It is free.

> You can add custom domains to any Heroku app. Adding domains does not incur extra charges. For security purposes, you must verify your Heroku account to add domains to apps.
>   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains